# Is there an anti-masturbation dolphin mascot named Fappy who was arrested for public masturbation at Sea World?

Tags: united-states, zoology, sexuality

[Christian Anti-Masturbation’s Mascot “Fappy” Arrested For Public Masturbation While Swimming Naked With The Dolphins At Sea World In San Diego](http://cbsnews.com.co/christian-anti-masturbations-mascot-arrested/)

From [his Facebook page](https://www.facebook.com/fappythedolphin), he seems to be a stand-up comic, but there are also several pictures shown there and in the article in classrooms with small kids.

The article calls him "a mascot for a Christian anti-masturbation group", but the Facebook page doesn't look like something such a group would like much, as it has things like a painting of naked Donald Trump and countless jokes about the topic.

So it seems like he exists, but:

1. Is he really a mascot for a Christian anti-masturbation group?
2. Was he really arrested as described?

Despite seeming to be a comic/satire thing, [people seem to believe it was real, making it notable](http://www.goddiscussion.com/108512/facebook-page-has-people-across-the-internet-asking-is-this-for-real-when-it-comes-to-fappy-the-anti-masturbation-dolphin/) (h/tip @OddThinking).

Comment: According to Meta notability rules (only 6 upvotes, unfortunately), an onbiously satirical claim **must be shown to be believed as real by many people** to be notable. http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1880/is-humor-and-satire-acceptable-for-notable-claims

Comment: @user5341: I agreed with you, and closed it. Then [found evidence that it was believed](http://www.goddiscussion.com/108512/facebook-page-has-people-across-the-internet-asking-is-this-for-real-when-it-comes-to-fappy-the-anti-masturbation-dolphin/) and reopened it.

Comment: @Oddthinking - the reopen should probably require a comment like a VTC, and similarly post it as a comment. That way, (1) people know why there are VTRO votes and (2) people can judge if they should re-open without re-doing research. (3) side effect would be to avoid pestering comments like mine above :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is not true.

See for example [snopes](http://www.snopes.com/fappy-arrested-seaworld/):

> The fake mascot of the fictional organization Stop Masturbation Now is a mainstay of the fake news site NewsExaminer
>
> Despite Fappy's frequent appearances on the Internet, the mascot is a fictional character created as part of an elaborate and ongoing hoax.

Other - more or less reliable - news websites also call the mascot a hoax (partly in different contexts, but it's about the same mascot), among them [Vanity Fair](http://www.vanityfair.com/news/2013/12/twitter-hoaxes-2013), [Daily Mirror](http://www.mirror.co.uk/news/technology-science/technology/news-website-falls-hoax-claim-6676223), [Salon](https://www.salon.com/2013/12/18/top_10_internet_pranks_and_hoaxes_of_2013_partner/), or the [Daily Dot](http://www.dailydot.com/lol/michael-moore-fappy-the-dolphin-film-hoax/).

Note also that `cbsnews.com.co` is a fake news website, which is not affiliated with CBS News in any way.